# I cant use the objects attribute in django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a Projects model

```
class Projects(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=257, unique=True, null=False)
description = models.TextField()
active_issue_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # functiona bağlanmalı
solved_issue_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # functiona bağlanmalı
is_active = models.BooleanField()
start_date = models.DateTimeField()
deadline = models.DateTimeField()
```

and I want to use this project model `Projects.objects.all()` with this code but when I typed in pyCharm shows me this suggestion [image]

but while I try to use this model

```
class User(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = UserManager()
    related_group = models.CharField
    current_project = models.ForeignKey(to='core.Project', 
    related_name='current_project', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    total_worked_project = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # functiona bağla
    active_work_project_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)  # functiona bağla

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']
```

`
I can use User.objects.all() without suggestion what should I do anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm just don't follow some object's relation. Here it has no clue that this Model class has related `Manager`, that you can call with `objects`.

You can ignore it in PyCharm so it will not bother you.

More actions... => Ignore (...)